# Force windows to prompt authentication to shared folder/disable "remember my credentials"

Tags: permissions, authentication, password, credentials, shared-folders

Is there a way to force windows to prompt for credentials to a shared folder? We are in a domain environment with 50+ PCs. What I need is to have a shared folder on our server that has specific user permissions. I need these users to be able to access this folder from any PC in our network, and I **DO NOT** want windows to cache their credentials after the first logon. I need them to be required to enter their password every time they try to access the folder.

I have looked at options with net use and net view, however *there are other shared drives and folders that I do not want affected by this change* (they still need to be accessible without credentials and have the drives remembered on the pcs for all users).

I've also looked into options with UAC with no luck. I should also note that due to the field-specific software my client uses we have to disable UAC completely.

Is this something I might be able to accomplish with roaming profiles or enabling access-based enumeration for the folder?

I feel like this is something windows should be able to do and it has been too long since I've done sysadmin work that I just can't remember and Google is failing me today.

Windows 2008 R2 Standard
Windows 7 workstations

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can prevent caching of network credentials using a group policy. It's under:

```
Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\Security Options\
```

The setting you are after is: "Network Access: Do not allow storage of credentials or .NET Passports for network authentication"

Comment: Will this affect my other shares as well? I need the other shares to have quick access.

Comment: This will affect any shares you try to access form the machines you apply this policy to. You can limit what machines you apply the policy to, you can't limit what shares it applies to. I can't see any way you can do that.

Answer (score 2):

That's not how authentication and authorization works for domain members in an AD domain. Users don't provide their username and password to network resources in order to access those resources. As such there are no Windows credentials stored in Credentials Manager for domain resources.